# What is the concept of Head in Subversion and what is the difference to a Trunk

Tags: svn, configuration-management

I undrstand that a trunk is the "main" branch, and understand the concept of branches and tags. but where does the "head" comes into the picture? It seems it is the "latest" revision? if so than what is it's difference to a "trunk"

I'm sure I'm probably mixing unrelated fields, e.g. trunk is to branch as head is to tags?

I dug into some documentations, but I must admit that it wasn't that clear to me time limiting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HEAD means the most recent revision of them all. Trunk it the branch where most development happens (depends on branching strategy).

For more revision keywords see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords). It also describes [repository layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout)

Comment: Thanks! So the head is the latest revision of the trunk? how do you call the latest revision of a branch?

Comment: you can have trunk@HEAD and branches/mybranch@HEAD, basically it means that you have the latest version available of whatever tree you're using. When you run `svn update` without revision parameter, it'll update to HEAD